# start up disk creator doesnt have ubuntu file

Tags: usb-drive

Step 5 of How to create bootable USB stick on ubuntu "Select the file and click 'Open'." Doesnt show anything under Desktop after I click "Other".. Its just blank.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the **Other** button to browse for an Ubuntu installation iso file, Startup Disk Creator looks for a file with an .iso extension which has a name similar in form to this file: xubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso . If there is a file like that on your desktop, then Startup Disk Creator should recognize it.